# where to save a custom log file in android?

Tags: android

I created a class for write a log file and works very well:

```
public class LogFile {

String route;
Context context;

public LogFile(Context context, String date) {
    this.context = context;
    this.route= context.getFilesDir() + "/log_"+date+".txt";
}

public void appendLog(String text){       

    File logFile = new File(ruta);

    if (!logFile.exists()){
        try{
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } 
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

But the route that this generates is /data/data/com.myAplication.myAplication/files/log_20130717.txt
And I cant access this directory from my device. I need to access this file if a problem occurs from the device. With the file explorer of my tablet I see the directories: /root/data and /root/Android/data. Does android helps to create my aplication directory inside any of these directories?. Otherwise, I tried to put the file in "sdcard/log_20130717.txt" but I get permission denied.

What do you suggest me to do?.

Comment: If privacy isn't an issue, why not save it on the sdcard? And, what exactly is "sdcard/log.file". Is it a path? Have you tried getting the path to external storage(through `String exPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutepath()`) and then saving your file to exPath + "/" + log.file?

Comment: thanks this works. But what if I my device doesnt have sdcard?

Comment: For an application I am working on, I save a number of files to the internal memory. When these files need to be updated, I retrieve them from the internal memory, update them, and write them back. If this is what you are looking for, I can post an answer with code examples.

Comment: yes, please. This can be an alternative if there is no sdcard. Thank you :)

Comment: I overlooked the fact that you need to access the `logFile` from outside your application. In my case, I only need to read/update the files from within my application. So, my code will not be of much help to you. If you need to view the `logFile(s)`, you can open the DDMS perspective in Eclipse and look under 'File Explorer'.

Comment: It's ok vikram. I got a solution that can work for me using File logFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name); I get a directory of my app inside /Android/data/ and I have access to my log file from there. Thank you so much for your help :).

Comment: hey, no problem. Glad, I could (somewhat) help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place it in [`externalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), and don't forget to get `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) API to easily write to files. For example, this will do what you want:

```
$.write(text, FileLocation.EXTERNAL, "log_"+date+".txt", true, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, this is what works for me. After a little bit more research, I found out how to store my data in the path  /root/Android/data/:

```
public class LogFile {

String name;
Context context;


public LogFile(Context context, String name) {

    this.context = context;
    this.name="log_"+name+".txt";

}

public void appendLog(String text){       

    File logFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name);


    if (!logFile.exists()){
        try{
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } 
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Using

```
File logFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name);
```

Android automatically creates a directory with the name of my project, getting: /root/Android/data/com.myAPP.myApp/files/ . Inside files I get my custom log created and even important, when my app is uninstalled, this directory gets delete. Also, the user has access to this file aswell.